# How to specialize (overload) behavior of a function for a single type?

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, typeclass

I'm working through Real World Haskell, and as part of an exercise realized I wanted a function similar to `show :: Show(a) => a -> String`, but which leaves Strings untouched (rather than escaping quotes). In pseudocode, what I want is:

```hs
show' :: String -> String
show' = id

show':: Show(a) => a -> String
show' = show
```

Obviously this doesn't work (ghc complains of multiple type signatures and multiple declarations). It seems like I should use typeclasses instead. When I try to write this, the compiler keeps suggesting I add more more language extensions:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, UndecidableInstances, IncoherentInstances #-}

class Show' a where
  show' :: a -> String

instance Show' String where
  show' = id

instance (Show a) => Show' a where
  show' = show

-- x == "abc"
x = show' "abc"
y = show' 9
```

At first this seems to work: `x == "abc"` and `y == "9"` as expected. But when I try to use this in another polymorphic function, the compiler seems to always resolve it to the general implementation:

```hs
use :: (Show a) => a -> String
use x = show' x

-- z == "\"abc\""
z = use "abc"
```

So I'm doing something wrong here, and I wonder if there is a way to do this without a bunch of language extensions (some of these don't seem like things I ought to use recklessly). How can I define this `show'` using the existing `show` function?

Comment: I'm surprised no one's mentioned this, but you shouldn't need `IncoherentInstances`. Get rid of it and write the catch-all `instance` with `instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} Show a => Show' a where show' = show`. Then the definition of `use` should error, since (as the accepted answer explains) it *is* wrong. Basically, `IncoherentInstances` is says to GHC "even though there are multiple instances for some types, all the instances actually agree so you can choose between them however you want", which is not true here. `OVERLAPPABLE` says the truth: there is only one valid instance for a type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From a comment of the OP:

> [I] was surprised that such a simple function to describe was so difficult to implement.

That's no simple function at all, since it sort-of breaks the usual guarantees of typeclass-based polymorphism. When we see an instance

```
instance Show' a => Show' [a] where ...
```

we usually assume this instance to be taken for all list types, with no exceptions. Universal quantification over types `a` really means `forall a`.

Overlapping / incoherent instances break this assumption, and allow "special cases" like yours, as David pointed out in his answer. That's one possible solution, but note that by breaking the assumption above, overlapping / incoherent instances make instance resolution rather fragile, sometimes leading to the wrong instance being taken, unexpectedly.

As an alternative, you can consider exploiting the `Typeable` typeclass which I believe is less controversial:

```
import Data.Typeable

show' :: (Show a, Typeable a) => a -> String
show' x = case cast x of
   Just s  -> s           -- cast succeeded, it is a string
   Nothing -> show x      -- case failed, it is not a string
```

Note that the presence of `Typeable` makes it evident, in the type, that this function is defined using ad-hoc polymorphism, allowing us to check whether `a` is such and such type, which is normally impossible under parametric polymorphism.

Note that this does not require `IncoherentInstances` nor `OverlappingInstances`.

Comment: (I just realized that I essentially re-wrote a 2016 answer of mine to the duplicate found by Daniel Wagner.)

Answer (score 2):

The only thing use knows about the type of its argument is that it's an instance of `Show`. Since this is all it knows, it *must* use the "general" instance which only requires `Show`.

What you really want, instead of that, is to tell it that it can be any instance of `Show'` (rather than any instance of `Show`).  A small change fixes this:

```
use :: (Show' a) => a -> String
```

An aside: If I remember correctly, `IncoherentInstances` can occasionally cause some issues. I think it is ok here, but this is something to keep in mind if you are creating more instances in the same file that has that extension enabled.

`UndecidableInstances` can potentially cause the type checker (and hence the compiler as a whole) to go into an infinite loop, if there is a cycle in dependencies between instances of a type class. That isn't the case here, but it's worth mentioning.

To answer your other question: It is not possible to do this specific thing without using these language extensions. Is there more context to this problem (details you've left out, etc)? Maybe there is a better way to approach the larger problem.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work when I fix that and add MonoLocalBinds. The context is really just that I'm reading and learning, and was surprised that such a simple function to describe was so difficult to implement.

Comment: @HarrisEnniss The difficulty arises because one case is completely polymorphic (with a constraint of `Show`) and the other case is a specific, concrete type (`String`). For what it's worth, in my experience, this kind of scenario does not happen too much in practice and, in the infrequent cases when it *is* unavoidable, I believe this implementation pattern is usually an acceptable solution.